# Creating iterated dataframes for a simulation function

Tags: r, iteration, simulation

I'm trying to create a function which compares the operating characteristics of a couple types of penalized regression techniques. To do this, I'd like to write a simulation in R which repeats the two types of regressions, but on new data each time.

I've already gotten this accomplished for a single case (i.e. only generating 1 case of sample data), but I'm having trouble generalizing this via creating n repetitions of sample data for my simulation. Here's some sample code which will hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish (note that I already have my function for generating data working).

Let's call my data-generating function `data_fun`, which takes on arguments: `n` (sample size) and `sigma` (variance re: the sampling distributions for my generated data). Let's call my simulation function `sim_fun`, which also takes on arguments: `n` and `sigma`, by also `r`, which represents the number of simulation datasets I'd like to create.

To store each of my generated datasets, I'll create an empty list called data:

```
data<-list()
```

I'd like to create r new datasets from my data_fun function, and store them in the data list:

```
sim_fun<-function(n,sigma,r){
  for(i in 1:r){
   data[[i]]<-data_fun(n,sigma)
  }
return(data) 
}
```

This works. However, here comes the part I can't figure out yet: I'd like to split each dataset in `data` in 2/3 training data and 1/3 test data. Here's the code I'd use if I were only doing this once:

```
library("caret")
#Determine number of observations in the training and test sets:
 sample_n<-floor((2/3)*nrow(data))

#Make random sampling index 
sample_index<-sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), size=sample_n)

#Sample from data
train <- data[sample_index,]
test <- data[-sample_index,]
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this: I've tried making empty list for train and test so that I can store the ith partitioned dataset into the ith train/test set inside the loop:

```
train<-list()
test<-list()

train[[i]] <- data[[i]][sample_index,]
test[[i]] <- data[[i]][-sample_index,]
```

But I don't think this works. I'd ultimately like `r` datasets separated into r training and test datasets.

I'm sorry I did not include a reproducible example. I appreciate any tips you could give!

Thanks

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Thanks, got it working. Just a typo: lot's of [[i]]s to miss!

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Ridge and PLSR. I'm using glmnet and pls for those.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the unnecessary question; just a typo on my part. This code works for what I was trying to accomplish:

```
#Generate empty lists to store our various outputs (depends on how many reps)
data<-list()
train<- list()
x_train<-list()
y_train<-list()
test<-list()
x_test<-list()
y_test<-list()
sample_n<-list()

#Assign argument-specified data to data list

sim_fun<-function(n,sigma,r){
  for (i in 1:r){
    data[[i]]<-data_fun(n,sigma)


  #Define training and test data
    #Separate into 2/3 training dataset, 1/3 test dataset
    library("caret")
    sample_n[[i]]<-floor((2/3)*nrow(data[[i]]))

  #Make random sampling index 
    sample_index<-sample(seq_len(nrow(data[[i]])), size=sample_n[[i]])

  #Sample from data
    train[[i]] <- data[[i]][sample_index,]
    test[[i]] <- data[[i]][-sample_index,]

    x_train[[i]]<- as.matrix(train[[i]][,-1])
    y_train[[i]]<- (train[[i]][,1])

    x_test[[i]]<- as.matrix(test[[i]][,-1])
    y_test[[i]]<- (test[[i]][,1])
  }
  return("insert relevant output lists")
}
```